# Hide a div after submission

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, form-submit

I am working on our site which uses a CMS and limited scope to chnage the coding of certain elements. I am trying to hide a div upon the submission of a form. The code pertaining to the sumbit button is below and I cannot edit this code. I am trying to determine what function would needed to be edited to allow a div to be hidden. I can post additional code from the header but I am not exactly sure what the relevant scripts are

```
<input type="submit" name="PC3638$btnNext" value="Donate Now" onclick="(function(btn){var bDisableMe=true;__doPostBack(&#39;PC3638$btnNext&#39;,&#39;&#39;);btn.disabled=bDisableMe;})(this);return false;" id="PC3638_btnNext" class="BBFormSubmitButton DonationSubmitButton" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have access to any backend code, so your best friend will be JS and some workarounds,
You need to save something on the browser to be able to read it after form submit-reload.

- What about writing a small function to [create a cookie using js](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=read%20write%20cookie%20javascript) and then read form this cookie and hide the div based on this cookie value?
- Or you can submit with [adding a hash # value in the url](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=add%20hash%20to%20url%20on%20submit) and also using the JS read this hash code and hide your div when it exists

Comment: Amr, given I can't edit the coding of the submit button, would this second otion still be feasible? I can inject some code into the <head> but not edit what the CMS creates be default.

Comment: If you can add some code in the header, you can bind a click event to the button and do the first option "cookies" because I don't think that the second one will work in that case, because you can't edit the submit url easily.

Answer (score -1):

some jquery here.

```
$('.BBFormSubmitButton').on('click', function(){
    // Do whatever
});
```

Please search before you ask.

Comment: Are you sure the OP is using jQuery? It's not mentioned in the tags, or in the questions.

Comment: what cms does not use jquery? even if it doesn't, including jquery is not that hard

Comment: The CMS is not using JQuery and as I stated, I cannot edit this portion of the code to add in a function otherwise I would just call something additionally. I am stuck with the line of code attached to the submit button currently so I need some kind of work around

Comment: just put that with a script tag around it in you header. you did say you can edit the header. with this solution you do not have to edit the portion that you show. this is just attaching an event handler to the button.